# Angular interceptor cache with multi call on same time

Tags: angular

I have an angular app and on a page there is the same component 6 time and each of them are making an API call. For some reason I don't want to fix this call in it's service, but rather I want a generic solution for every API calls in every services.

I would like a solution to intercept each API call, save the result and if I detect the same query in the next 2 seconds, I will use the saved result.

I've made an angular interceptor, it works, but not on the page with the 6 parallel API calls. It seems I can't write my first cache loading state of the first call before the next 5 calls are trying to read it.

Here is the code, please can you help me ?

```
private cache: Map<string, HttpValues> = new Map();

intercept(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    return next.handle(req);
  }
  if (req.headers.get('reset')) {
    this.cache.delete(req.urlWithParams);
  }
  console.log(`-> search in cache`, req.urlWithParams);
  const cachedResponse = this.cache.get(req.urlWithParams);
  // si on ne trouve pas de réponse en cache, on la charge et on la met en cache
  if (!cachedResponse) {
    console.log('cache miss');
    return this.setCacheAndReturnResponse(req, next);
  }
  if (cachedResponse) {
    console.log('cache hit');
    if (req.body !== cachedResponse?.request?.body
      || cachedResponse?.date?.getTime() + 2000 > new Date().getTime()) {
      console.log('cache hit but not valid');
      return this.setCacheAndReturnResponse(req, next);
    }
    if (cachedResponse.responseStatus === ResponseStatusEnum.LOADING) {
      console.log('cache hit but loading');
      return new Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>>(observer => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (cachedResponse.responseStatus === ResponseStatusEnum.LOADED) {
            observer.next(cachedResponse.response);
            observer.complete();
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
        }, 50);
      });
    }
  }
}

private setCacheAndReturnResponse(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  this.cache.set(
    req.urlWithParams,
    {
      request : req,
      response : null,
      date : new Date(),
      responseStatus: ResponseStatusEnum.LOADING
    }
  );
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
    tap(stateEvent => {
      if (stateEvent instanceof HttpResponse) {
        const cachedResponse = this.cache.get(req.urlWithParams);
          this.cache.set(
            req.urlWithParams,
            {...cachedResponse, responseStatus: ResponseStatusEnum.LOADED, response: stateEvent.clone()}
          );
        } else {
          this.cache.delete(req.urlWithParams);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```